# Send Email from an Asp.Net Webform Application using Microsoft Outlook

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an`asp.net` web form which on click of a button sends i want an email to be sent to my Microsoft outlook email account. I have done this on other

websites but that was using hotmail but all external web email providers are blocked by the companies firewall (as i tried setting up a gmail account) so

i need to use Outlook but i have not idea on how to implent this and solutions i have seen on Google dont seem to work. I dont know if it'll make a

difference or not but i have been informed that the users password epxires every 30days so i suspect i'll need to use windows authenication or something

but not sure.

I'm not sure on how Outlook send the email as i know from past experience from using hotmail that the email is just sent on click of the button but i'm

not sure if outlook would open the email window for the user to click the send button. If it does, i need the information captured on the webform to be

containd in the email and the content of the email body not to be altered (if this can be done, again not ot sure if it can but not a problem if it

can't).

Below is the code i used for when i tried gmail but as i said i was told it wouldnt be allowed.

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

protected void BtnSuggestPlace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            #region Email
            try
            {
                //Creates the email object to be sent
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

                //Adds your email address to the recipients
                msg.To.Add("MyEmailAddress@Test.co.uk");

                //Configures the address you are sending the email from
                MailAddress address = new MailAddress("EmailAddress@Test.com");
                msg.From = address;

                //Allows HTML to be used when setting up the email body
                msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

                //Email subjects title
                msg.Subject = "Place Suggestion";

                msg.Body = "<b>" + lblPlace.Text + "</b>" + "&nbsp;" + fldPlace.Text
                           + Environment.NewLine.ToString() +
                           "<b>" + lblLocation.Text + "</b>" + "&nbsp;" + fldLocation.Text
                           + Environment.NewLine.ToString() +
                           "<b>" + lblName.Text + "</b>" + "&nbsp;" + fldName.Text;

                //Configures the SmtpClient to send the mail
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
                client.EnableSsl = true; //only enable this if the provider requires it

                //Setup credentials to login to the sender email address ("UserName", "Password")
                NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("MyEmailAddress@Test.co.uk", "MyPassword");
                client.Credentials = credentials;

                //Send the email
                client.Send(msg);
            }
            catch
            {
                //Lets the user know if the email has failed
                lblNotSent.Text = "<div class=\"row\">" + "<div class=\"col-sm-12\">" + "There was a problem sending your suggestion. Please try again." 

+ "</div>" + "</div>" + "<div class=\"form-group\">" + "<div class=\"col-sm-12\">" + "If the error persists, please contact Antony." + "</div>" + 

"</div>";
            }
            #endregion
}
```

Comment: You are trying to send from your local account through the Google SMTP proxy?

Comment: @PatrickHofman The code above is what i used and works to send an email from an hotmail accounf to another hotmail acc.  I know this code will not work for Microsoft Outlook and as i said all web emails (hotmail, gmail, yahoo etc) are blocked. If you have a suggestion to clean up the above code, please help and i can see if it'll work or not.

Comment: Yes, use the server settings from your work place.

Comment: are you trying to send from a Work Domain \ MS Exchange or Outlook.com?

Comment: @SimonPrice From MS Exchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit 2: Now we have established your going through exchance this is how my code has always worked

```
    SmtpClient sptmClient = new SmtpClient("exchange server name")
MailMessage m = new MailMessage();
m.To.Add(new MailAddress("Address"));
m.From = new MailAddress("");
m.Subject = "";
m.Body = "";
m.IsBodyHtml = true;
sptmClient.Send(m);
```

but there is another answer on here that uses outlook interoperlation that might work better for you

Comment: I cant use gmail at all.  The email send functionality will need to use Microsoft Outlook (not outlook.com).  This will then send an email from the users email address another one and will also need to CC another user i have just been told.

Comment: @murday1983 sorry, I have only just seen this comment. With GMail, you have to reduce your gmail security settings. Its an absolute pig to do too. But try sending and youll receive a message from gmail, and then you can go through your settings, and may need to change your password and will need to check some boxes saying that you accept the risks of lower security

Answer (score 1):

With Exchange it must work.

test this :

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

 private void SendWithExchange()
            {

                Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
                Outlook.MailItem mail = oApp.CreateItem(
                    Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as Outlook.MailItem;
                mail.Subject = "Exemple à tester";
                Outlook.AddressEntry currentUser =
                    oApp.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry;
                if (currentUser.Type == "EX")
                {
                    Outlook.ExchangeUser manager =
                        currentUser.GetExchangeUser();
                    mail.Recipients.Add(manager.PrimarySmtpAddress);
                    mail.Recipients.ResolveAll();
                    //mail.Attachments.Add(@"c:\sales reports\fy06q4.xlsx",
                    //    Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, Type.Missing,
                    //    Type.Missing);
                    mail.Send();
                }
            }
```